# Create an Avro GenericRecord using an Avro Schema and JSON data

Tags: java, json, avro

I'm trying to generate an Avro GenericRecord using the following schema and the JSON data.

The Avro schema

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Person",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "city",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "gender",
      "type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "Gender",
        "symbols": ["MALE", "FEMALE"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON data

```
{"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York", "gender": "MALE"}
```

The code I use to generate a GenericRecord is

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Schema schema = readSchema();
        JsonNode data = readData();
        GenericRecord genericRecord = convertJsonToAvro(data, schema);
        System.out.println(genericRecord);
    }

    public static GenericRecord convertJsonToAvro(JsonNode jsonNode, Schema avroSchema) throws IOException {
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(avroSchema);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(avroSchema, jsonNode.toString());
        return reader.read(null, decoder);
    }

    private static Schema readSchema() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/person.avsc");
        return new Schema.Parser().parse(inputStream);

    }

    private static JsonNode readData() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample_data/person.json");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, JsonNode.class);
    }

}
```

From the above code, I can successfully generate a GenericRecord. But when the schemas enum field is changed to an optional field like below, it throws an error.

Optional field

```
{
    "name": "gender",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "type": "enum",
            "name": "Gender",
            "symbols": ["MALE", "FEMALE"]
        }
    ],
    "default": null
}
```

The error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING
at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.error(JsonDecoder.java:511)
at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readIndex(JsonDecoder.java:430)
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:282)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:188)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:260)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:248)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)
at com.generic.Main.convertJsonToAvro(Main.java:27)
at com.generic.Main.main(Main.java:20)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I highly appreciate if someone can explain what is happening here and the way to fix this error. I know about the [allegro/json-avro-converter](https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter) but I would like to do this without it. A code example would be very helpful.

Please find the dependencies I used for the above code

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro', version: '1.11.3'
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.16.0'
```

Comment: Did you try `{"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York", "gender": null}`?

Comment: Hi @phuongnq1995, thank you for the reply. Yes, it works.

Comment: No problem, I posted the answer, can u mark it as correct?

Comment: Sorry, cannot mark it as correct since it does not accept a String value like "MALE" or "FEMALE".

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

The enum type in side `gender` is `Gender`, when you consider that property as an object, the payload should contain it as child properties.

This is a not-null `gender` payload:

```
{"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York", "gender": {"Gender": "MALE"}}
```

Then here is your `GenericRecord`:

```
{"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York", "gender": "MALE"}
```

This is a null `gender` payload

```
{"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York", "gender": null}
```

Comment: I'm not posting an empty String, I'm posting a String value "MALE". But as mentioned above, it throws an error.

Comment: @Prasad Thanks for your response, you're correct about the payload, I tested it & updated the answer. Thanks